# How can I replace class on anchor tag without breaking functionality?

Tags: html, css, anchor

In the code below I have `anchor tag` where window and less class are applied. How can I remove anchor tag such that classes that are applied to anchor tags are used in the code and functionality does

Comment: `.window .read-window` <-- your selector is not going to allow you to remove it. So you would need to alter your selector.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want the following html:

```html
 <div class="read-window-links">
    <span class="read-window window">
        <p>${properties.readText}</p>
    </span>

    <span class="read-window less hidden">
        <p>${properties.readLessLinkText}</p>
    </span>
</div>
```

I've removed the `a` tags and added the `a` classes to the child `span` tags.

Your css will no longer work because you are matching based on DOM hierarchy, not just class name. See [this article](https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/) for a more in-depth treatment, but essentially in e.g. this section:

```css
.read-window-section .read-window-links .window .read-window p:after {
  content: url(down_arrow_icon.png);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

you are saying, "set `content` to `url(down_arrow_icon.png)` and `display` to `inline-block` for a `p` which is a descendant of an element with class `read-window` which is a descendant of an element with class `window` which is a descendant of an element with class `read-window-links`..." etc. If you change the DOM hierarchy, you need to change your css to match, which means something like

```html
<span class="read-window window">
    <p>${properties.readText}</p>
</span>
```

```css
.read-window-section .read-window-links .window.read-window p:after {
  content: url(down_arrow_icon.png);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Notice how there is no space between `.window` and `.read-window`, which means "match an element with both `.window` and `.read-window` classes."

Comment: Removing .window breaks the original functionality